# How to stop code from running on a specific date

Tags: javascript, date

I want to stop a specific part of my code from running when its *29th of may*. Someone can help me out on this with `jQuery` or `JavaScript`.

Comment: Note that if you implement this in client-side code the user could get around it by changing the system time on their device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this,

```
var CurrentDate = new Date();
var YourSelectedDate = new Date(2016, 04, 29, 10, 15); //Here it is 29th may 2016

    if(CurrentDate > YourSelectedDate ){
        //CurrentDate is more than YourSelectedDate 
       // Display warning message or whatever you want to display.
    }
    else{
        //YourSelectedDate is more than CurrentDate
        //put your code in this part.
    }
```

Comment: @SagarR If a client change date of own system, this code doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

```
var diff = ( new Date('2016/05/29 00:00:01') - new Date() );
if( diff > 0 ){
   /*   Your Code here  */
}
```

If the **diff** is negative then today date exceed the May 29th

Comment: Why would you use the very problematic parsing of a string rather than setting the values directly?

Answer (score 0):

*This is an example*

You can work with [Date objects](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp);

Here is something you can start with, there are much better ways to do this, because you didn't show any code i assume you do not know Date Objects, have fun coding!

```
var randDate = new Date(2016, 04, 29, 10, 15);
randDate.setHours(0);
randDate.setMinutes(0);
randDate.setSeconds(0);
randDate.setMilliseconds(0);

var target = new Date(2016, 04, 29); 

target.setHours(0);
target.setMinutes(0);
target.setSeconds(0);
target.setMilliseconds(0);

console.log(target.getTime() === randDate.getTime());


//output: true
```

**Example II**

```
var randDate = new Date(2016, 04, 29, 10, 15);
//randDate is your now() on any day
randDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
var now = new Date();
now.setHours(0,0,0,0);
//strips h, m, s, ms from var now && var randDate



var target = new Date(2016, 04, 29);
//set up your target
target.setHours(0,0,0,0);
//strips h, m, s, ms if needed


console.log(target.getTime() === randDate.getTime());
//output: true
console.log(target.getTime() === now.getTime());
//output: false (Mon May 09 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Romance (zomertijd)))
```

Comment: what does the 10 and 15 mean in randDate?

Comment: new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds); There is a link with date objects info ;) Feel free to ask :-)

Comment: Thanks I check out your link:) And why is this month 4 , is it because january is 0?